# What data will be rolled back on secondary node

Tags: mongodb

When the replica set needs to elect a new primary, the updaed data will be still saved in old primary node, and it will generate a bson file. But i also found there is a bson file in secondary node sometimes. what data will be rollback in secondary node? Thanks!
The following is my case:

1. this cluster have 3 nodes:server1, server2 and server3, the server1 is primary
2. insert a large amounts of data
3. during inserting, the server1 don't connect to server2 and server3, so the cluster will elect the new primary
4. still be inserting data
5. the server2 is elected as the primary
6. Network restoration, the server1 can connect to serve2 and server3
7. the server1 change the state from ROLLBACK to SECONDARY
8. find the server1 has a bson file in rollback folder.
9. but also find the server3 has a bson file in rollback folder

why do the server3 have a bson file? what data will be rollback?

Comment: Question is not clear, can you give specific example.

Comment: you say server3 was primary - is that a typo? if server 1 is unreachable it would only cause new election if 1 was primary.

Comment: Sorry, i already change it, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the secondary that will become the new primary is behind the other secondary in replication. This can for example happen if you specified manual priorities for the replica members as stated here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/#replica-set-node-priority-configuration

In that case, the other secondary also needs to rollback to the current state of the new primary.

Comment: I see. but their priorities are same,if the server2 is behind the serve3 in replication, then the server2 can't be elected as the primary.

Comment: Even with no priorities set, this case does happen occasionally. One possible explanation is a clock skew between the two secondaries. You will find that the rollback on the secondary is usually very small, like a few seconds. However, you should still look at the rolled-back documents (with bsondump for example) and decide if you need to reimport the lost data. Be careful with this process though, as this is a very manual operation and may cause problems with e.g. unique monotonically increasing indexes.

Comment: Can you detailed describe that how do the clock skew affect replication? Thanks! I just checked the log file and found there is such error message : "replSet error possible failover clock skew issue? 5046c5c2:1"

Comment: If there is a clock skew, the oplog timestamps of the new primary could be behind the old primary, which would make it possible for new oplog entries to have a timestamp older than some previous entries on the other secondary (and cause rollback).

Normally an election will choose the primary with the most current oplog, but if you have changed the number of votes or there is some other connectivity problem that influences the election, it's possible that a secondary may be chosen which does not have the most current oplog and also causes rollback.